# how to trigger a PostBack on the whole page from a button click in update panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, entity-framework-6

here's the updatepanel and i need to do that AsyncPostBackTrigger which run some scripts and code behind on other controls

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>

          <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" SingleClick="true" SingleClickText="Processing..." AutoPostBack="true" OnClick="RadButton1_Click" Text="Create Order" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="12" BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" Skin="Bootstrap" CssClass="auto-style5"  >
          </telerik:RadButton>

       </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>

           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadButton1" EventName="Click" />

       </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On click function

```
protected void RadButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   ///some logic///
   /////DO PostBack Here///
}
```

Comment: Put your "other controls" into `updatepanel`s and call `updatepanelOther.Update()` in your `Create_Order_Click`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this example.  Remove appropriate comments to experience its behavior, and learn.  Thanks.  :)

aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TriggerPostBack.aspx.cs" Inherits="FredWebForm.TriggerPostBack" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <%-- removed OnClick="RadButton1_Click" from radio button--%>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" SingleClick="true" SingleClickText="Processing..." AutoPostBack="true" Text="Create Order" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="12" BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" Skin="Bootstrap" CssClass="auto-style5"></asp:RadioButton>
            <asp:Label ID="StuffInUpdatePanelChangesAsyncPostBackTrigger" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <%--<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadButton1" EventName="CheckedChanged" />--%>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="RadButton1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Label ID="StuffOutsideUpdatePanelNOCHANGEChangesAsyncPostBackTrigger" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            StuffInUpdatePanelChangesAsyncPostBackTrigger.Text = "StuffInUpdatePanelChangesAsyncPostBackTrigger";
            StuffOutsideUpdatePanelNOCHANGEChangesAsyncPostBackTrigger.Text = "StuffOutsideUpdatePanelNOCHANGEChangesAsyncPostBackTrigger";
        }

    }
```